# Execute command with shell script with a different user and pass all arguments to it

Tags: bash

I want to pass arguments to a shell script and execute a command from a different user with those arguments.

First try:

```bash
su username -c 'ls "$@"'
```

does not work at all. So I googled and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699986) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75411244/2731944). Both recommending to use `$*` instead of `$@`.

So I tried:

```bash
su username -c "ls $*"
```

But that does not work for arguments with white space in it. E.g. `./my_script.sh -a "directory name with spaces in it"` does not work.

So how can I pass multiple arguments including white space to my command?

Comment: Try `su username -c ls "$@"`

Comment: `"$@"` is passed to `su` then and not to `ls`.

Comment: Can you use `sudo` instead of `su`? Its argument handling is much cleaner for things like this. `sudo -u username ls "$@"` should work.

Comment: Anything recommending `$*` over `"$@"` is full-stop wrong in an overwhelming majority of cases.

Comment: I didn't vote on this but it seems a little vague IMO. Providing a [mre] is always a good idea. So in this case: a runnable shell script including shebang, how you are running it, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @miken32 `su username -c 'ls "$@"'` is the minimal reproducible example. It is a shell script and the most minimal that I can imagine. Shebang would be redundant, because I tagged my question with `bash`. Showing the output of the command would only make the question look more confusing. It stated clearly that the script does not handle white space in its arguments and that I want it to be able to handle white space. It was enough for multiple people answering to come up with a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays on linux we have `runuser`.

```
runuser -u username -- ls "$@"
```

Comment: That does not work. `"$@"` is passes to `runuser` instead of `ls`.

Comment: Yes, I have tested. Creating a script `#!/bin/sh` `runuser -u nobody ls "$@"` and executing `bash ./script.sh /tmp` outputs the content of `/tmp` directory.  What does it mean "not work"? What _happens_? What does not happen? Is there an error message?

Comment: `"$@" is passes to runuser instead of ls` That is true, and what you mean is that `-options` are still parsed by `runuser`. Let's fix it with `--`! See `man runuser`.

Comment: Great, that is more simplistic and even works with my php version: `runuser -u www-data -- php /var/www/nextcloud/occ "$@"`

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
su - username -c 'echo "$@"' -- bash "$@"
```

---

The difference between `$@` and `$*`: Without quotes (don't do this!), there is no difference. With double quotes, `"$@"` expands to each positional parameter as its own argument: `"$1" "$2"` ..., while `"$*"` expands to the single argument `"$1c$2c..."`, where '`c`' is the first character of `IFS`. You almost always want `"$@"` (QUOTED!). The same goes for arrays: `"${array[@]}"`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast and it works, but I really do not understand what `-- bash "$@"` is doing. I would be happy if someone could elaborate.

Comment: Ok, I made a minimal example, but for my actual command it still does not work :( Here is my command: `su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'php /var/www/nextcloud/occ "$@"'`. If I append `-- bash "$@"` it does not help.

Comment: Works also with php, see edited post

Comment: @Toxiro, "_but I really do not understand what `-- bash "$@"` is doing. I would be happy if someone could elaborate_", just search for and see in example [What does `$@` mean in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/) or [What is `$@` in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898665/).

Comment: @U880D I know what `$@` does. I don't know what `-- bash` does in this context with it and how it is passing the parameters to the inner function.

Comment: This is the syntax to use. This is the same as `find . -exec bash -c 'echo "$@"' -- bash 1 2 3 {} +`

Comment: @GillesQuénot Your php example passes the arguments to `stdin`, but my script requires to use them as command line parameters. If you replace your `test.php` script with `var_dump($argv);` no arguments are included.

Comment: It's just an example, search https://php.net for positional arguments. My solution works and fullfill your question.

Comment: `what -- bash does in this context with it`  Arguments to `sh -c` are assigned starting from `$0`, like `sh -c script $0 $1 $2`. The `--` becomes `$0`. See `man sh` or `man bash`. It is typical to pass an empty `--` or `_` as `$0` and use `"$@"`. You can also use a custom string to see in error messages `sh -c 'syntax(error' prog_name`.

Comment: @GillesQuénot You are right and I marked your answer as correct. I will open another question for the php version. Anyway this has nothing to do with PHP itself. The PHP script comes from a vendor and I cannot change it. My question (that I only added here in the comments) is about how to pass arguments to that php script (`occ`) with bash and not how to pass arguments to stdin.

Comment: @KamilCuk What does the `bash` after `--` do then? Why would I want to pass `bash` to `$1`?

Comment: I do not think I am able to explain it better. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144514/add-arguments-to-bash-c

Comment: Then I might not have asked clear enough. In your link it is explained that you pass `bash` to `$0` "since that's what $0 would normally be, but anything else would work.". And you explained that `--` will be passed to `$0`. I do not understand why in this solution we pass `--` AND `bash` before the first "real" argument. Would that not mean that `--` is passed to `$0` and `bash` is passed to `$1`?

Comment: No one cares in such contexts what is passed to `$0`. It is typical to use `--` or `_` as a placeholder. `Would that not mean that -- is passed to $0 and bash is passed to $1?` yes, bash is the first "real" argument and it mean that.